# WCF Channel State Not be updated

Tags: wcf, state, channel

I have a problem with my WCF application. I use a netTcpBinding for my application. And on the client side, I use ClientBase<> to connect to the host, and ICommunicationObject.State to check if the channel is still available.

The problem is after the "receiveTimeout", the TCP connection is cut, but in the client side, when I check the state, it still "Opened". And when I try to use it directly, there are exceptions.

To comfirm the disconnection of TCP socket, I use TCPView to monitor it. It is cut off after the timeout. But the state of channel is not updated.

---

Acutally, I add the diagnostic log in the config of server.
And I get an exception just after the timeout(at the same time the disconncection happens).

Here is the exception(on the server side):

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.

And if I try to call the service again from client, on the client side, I get this exception:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue.

I think it's normal for the exception on the client side. But I don't know if I need to handle the exceptions on the server side.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks every much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommunicationState` will stay as 'Opened' unless you explicitly `Close()` it or there is a fault with the Channel. Unfortunately, in your scenario until such point as you attempt to use said Channel, there is no way to determine if it is actually available apart from checking for an Exception.

I would suggest that you do not attempt to keep a Channel open past the point of it being used and explictly `Close()` it once you are done.

We have a wrapper that encapsulates the call, including the creation of a proxy, the service call itself and the subsequent closure of the channel and this works well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean the disconnection caused by the timeout is not a fault of the channel, so the state will not be updated?

Comment: Yes. Also, as posted, you should not keep the channel open which is causing the server error. Create the channel, make the call, close the channel. WCF is not designed for continuous connections to services.

Comment: Thanks, I also find something interesting at website MSDN

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wcf/thread/70145A68-F03C-4055-ABE7-307A957D5C38

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wcf/thread/5EBF50B5-0E15-40E1-8F3F-563845E6D7E2